# install python on windows via ansible

Tags: python, windows, installation, ansible

I am trying to install python 3 on windows, via ansible. I use following tasks, but the install does nothing (except downloading installer).

```
---

# download works OK
- name: Download python3.11
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.5/python-3.11.5-amd64.exe"
    dest: "c:/temp/python-3.11.5-amd64.exe"
  register: python_3_11_downloaded
  when: install_python|bool

# this does not work
- name: Install python3.11
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: c:\temp\python-3.11.5-amd64.exe
    product_id: "python_3.11"
    arguments:
      - /quiet
      # - /passive
      # - /unsinstall
  when: install_python|bool


# this does not work either
# - name: Install python3.11
#   ansible.windows.win_shell: "c:/temp/python-3.11.5-amd64.exe /quiet"
#   args:
#     chdir: C:/temp
#   when: install_python|bool
```